# Excel - auto-fill blank cells or 0 in B:B to a dummy e-mail address which changes sequentially

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I am creating a database in Excel that requires an e-mail address to be assigned to each row or user. While some users have an e-mail address in the original CSV file the majority do not. Each e-mail address will need to be unique. Is there any way to auto-fill all blank cells with an e-mail address which starts with a higher number each time it's used for example 1example@example.com, 2example@example.com etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email address you are going to autofill wouldn't have any significance, and you just want them to be unique, you can use the row number to make up an email address. One possible formula you can use is as follows,

```
=ROW()&"example@example.com"
```

If the above formula is used in 10th row, it would produce `10example@example.com`.

Comment: That's great, it works perfectly and is simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddyy if this solves your problem, go ahead and click the check mark next to it to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Done - Thanks for the heads up I was not too sure.